# d3 area has undesirable curves

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am using interpolate("cardinal") to connect these points and I am getting some weird curves. [image: See the image]

Notice how starting at July 5 the curve dips below zero then curves up to intersect the zero at July 6. Then it curves up after July 7 to come back down and intersect with July 8. How can I get curvy areas without these oddities?

Comment: try using `interpolate('monotone')`

Comment: try using interpolate("step-after"), this will give what you are looking for......

Comment: Thanks! While neither of these does exactly what I was hoping, monotone at least gets rid of the weird artifact of the curve going below zero and above the red point (for example.) Step after is a bit too right angled to show trends when there is more variation in the data on the y-axis. I am still wondering if there is a way to get a better curve. I might have to try and write my own maybe?

Comment: interpolate("linear") will get rid of the curves actually but if you want the curves to be there use a clip path on the area only